# application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: not executed when subclassing RBAppDelegate

Tags: redbeard-ios

When I subclass RBAppDelegate and override `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` it's never executed. Some hints with that?

```
class AppDelegate: RBAppDelegate {

    override func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        // won't be executed...
        configureStuff()

        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RBAppDelegate itself does not implement `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. It provides a `RBObserverCollection` property that allows multiple classes to observer events. Within your app you should create another class that implements the `RBAppDelegateObserver` protocol. Within this call you should implement `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and then add this to your RBAppDelegate class via `[appDelegate.observers addObserver:youclass]`

FYI: If you don't need the functionality provided by RBAppDelegate you can continue to use a normal class that implements the UIApplicationDelegate protocol as is usual.

Comment: Just to be clear: I have a `class AppDelegate: RBAppDelegate` with `override init()` (nothing else there) in which an instance of `class AppDelegateObserver: NSObject, RBAppDelegateObserver` is created and add it as observer with `observers.addObserver(AppDelegateObserver())`. In the `AppDelegateObserver` I implement a `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and us it as place for post-launch-configuration? This is the intended way and it's used to register multiple observers that itself reacts to the - so the `RBAppDelegateObserver` looks like - regular events, the `UIApplicationDelegate` uses?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Using this approach you can have multiple observers for UIApplicationDelegate events.